# Update image src using javascript is appending to root directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am loading a small file size, low res background-image using inline styling in the HTML, then using jQuery to load a high res version to replace it. The JavaScript uses a regular expression to get the low res image url, edit the url to the high res version, then:

**JS**

```
// Get low res url
...
// Edit low res url to high res url
var highResSrc = lowResSrc.replace(changeUrlRegex, '');
console.log("high res src " + highResSrc);

if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 700px)").matches) {
    console.log("Media match success");

    var img = new Image();
    console.log("new image created " + img.src);

    $(img).attr("src", highResSrc);
    console.log("img source set " + img.src);

    // After high res image has (pre)loaded, replace low res with it
    $(img).load(function() {
        console.log("img loaded");

        theDiv.css("background-image", "url(" + highResSrc + ")");
        console.log("div css changed");
    });
}
```

Shown below is the expected behaviour (Edge):

[image]
(Don't know why there's a 404, but you can ignore it)

IE11 (update: and Firefox 40) try to append the new high res src to the root directory:

[image]
And so the high res image fails to load.

Here is a side by side comparison:

[image]

Comment: IE11 seems to think the filename contains quotes. See what happens if you strip those.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I used another regex to remove the quotes if the regex matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mr Lister pointed out, the problem is some browsers put quote marks around the high res src string. Simple fix:

```
// If browser has put quotes around the high res src, remove the quotes
var removeQuotesRegex = /"(.*)"/;
if (removeQuotesRegex.test(highResBackgroundSrc)) {
    highResBackgroundSrc = highResBackgroundSrc.match(removeQuotesRegex)[1];
    console.log("high res src quotes removed " + highResBackgroundSrc);
} else {
    // No quotes to remove - do nothing
}
```